# Formatting data for an API JSON response

Tags: json-api

I have a couple of questions about formating data ready for an API JSON response.

1. If sending a datetime value (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format) in an API json response, if there is no datetime set, which one of these should it be:

   an empty string `""`

   A string of `"0000-00-00 00:00:00"`

   `null`
2. Is it good practice to make all values have a fixed datatype (not a mixed data type) in API responses? So for example, if a value will be an array, but there are no elements in the array, should the value be made an empty array `[]` rather than `false` or `null` so that value will always be an array?

Answer (score 0):

1. you can use null data type
2. You can use a nullable datatype e.g. `DateTime? MyNullableDate;`